# Can one be a plumber yet kosher

Tags: halacha

Can one work as a plumber but still be kosher.  The job involves getting filthy etc.  or is it considered a sinful occupation

Comment: Anecdotally, I know many Jewish plumbers and know of no objections to them

Answer (score 26):

Of course. There's nothing undignified about manual labor. See [Bava Basra 110a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.110a.5):

> Rav said to Rav Kahana: Skin a carcass in the market and take payment, and do not say: I am a great man and this is beneath me.

Rashbam elaborates:

> Meaning, skin it for payment in the marketplace, in public view. This is no desecration of Hashem's name, and we don't apply... [the admonition against] a Torah scholar wearing stained clothes, because there's no shame in supporting yourself with manual labor.

Answer (score 1):

There are professions which make an otherwise fit priest unfit to serve in the Temple. (Rambam. Mishne Torah Hilchot Melachim uMilchamot Chapter 1) because they are not dignified. He uses "Tanner" as an example.

There are professions that, if you join them, the court could compel you to divorce your wife. They are among the category of smelly and unpleasant things that linger on you when you come home. One of those professions is a "gatherer" - someone who gathers excrement for use in tanning hides. (Ketubot 77a)

Some aspects of plumbing, like septic tank cleaning, may put you at a halachic disadvantage but not "not kosher" as long as you wash after.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the answer